# Android custom view blurry after targetSdkVersion update to 15

Tags: android, view, draw, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am developing an application with a custom view.

```
public class Disegno extends View {
...
}
```

Until the last update no problem. Now, to enter the Bluetooth management, I need to increase the targetSdkVersion from 8 to 15. With this modify in the manifest, when I scale, **the drawing is blurry!**
I'm testing the app with several devices. Only devices with Android 4.0 and later is showing this problem. My HTC desire with custom Rom GingerBread is working! Can you help me!?

Take a look of following images:

!!!ARGh!!! I can't put any image because I'm new!!!!

[TARGETSDKVERSION 8](http://www.studioundici.it/disco/targetversion8.png)

[TARGETSDKVERSION 15](http://www.studioundici.it/disco/targetversion15.png)

Comment: [RESOLVED] I found this for another problem but is ok for me too! Just disable hardware accelerator for activity in manifest with:    `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` ... wow! It all right now!

Comment: It's more fitting to StackOverflow's Q&A style that you post the resolution as an answer to your question and accept it.